# iPhone - vibrate 5 times?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my application I want to be able to vibrate for a few seconds to alert the user something is taking place.

I have used the following code:

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
```

And this works as in it will vibrate once.

However I want to be able to vibrate 5 times, not continuously or anything I just want to be able to vibrate once, stop, vibrate again, stop and so on, is this possible and acceptable by Apple via the app store?

Comment: If you are enrolled in the iOS developer program, you might want to look at some of the new APIs in the beta that might become available in some future OS release, or look at the WWDC 2011 videos on Accessibility.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's currently the only method you can cause the phone to vibrate. But you could call that function 5 times!

Comment: And apple wont have an issue with calling it multiple times in a row?

Comment: Do you know how to make the phone vibrate continuously, such as when those massage apps do it? Thanks

Comment: `while(true) { AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
};`
 ;)

Comment: Check Louie's answer bellow. Calling the Vibrate method many times does not work. You need a timer to create some space between each call otherwise it will only vibrate once.

Answer (score 9):

You can do something like this..

Create an Integer. Create a 1 second timer. Hit a function every 1 second and make the phone vibrate while increasing the integer by 1. If the integer hits 5 kill the timer.

Doing it this way allows you to put a little space between vibrations so it will last as long as you'd like.

**in your .h file**

```
int vibrateCount;
NSTimer * vibrateTimer;

@property(nonatomic,assign)int vibrateCount;
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSTimer * vibrateTimer;
```

**in your .m file**

```
@synthesize vibrateCount,vibrateTimer;

//in viewDidLoad
vibrateCount = 0;

//put this where ever you want to start your vibrating
vibrateTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(vibratePhone) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];


-(void)vibratePhone {
vibrateCount = vibrateCount +1;

if(vibrateCount <= 5) {
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
}
else {

      //vibrated 5 times already kill timer and stop vibrating
      [vibrateTimer invalidate];

   }
}
```